# Page Load jQuery Form Submit does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, pageload

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                submitForm($("#login-user-one"));
            });

            function submitForm(form) {
                console.log($(form).attr("method"));
                $(form).submit();
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="login-user-one" name="login" method="POST" action="/test.html">
            <input name="userid" tabindex="1" value="MyUser">
            <input name="pass" type="password" tabindex="2" value="MyPass">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="1" tabindex="3">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't figure out why the above does not works. The log shows me the value of POST and yet it won't submit. There are no errors in the console.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t48hk9qx/

Comment: Not the issue but you're already passing a jQuery object to `submitForm`, you don't need to wrap it in `$(...)` again

Comment: @Phil do you know what the issue is?

Comment: It's uncommon to submit a POST form to a `.html` file. In fact, some web servers will reject such a request

Comment: @Phil its a fake url...you can change it to anything you want and it still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is a new one for me.

Because your form has a named element with `name="submit"`, that element reference is replacing the [`HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) function.

From the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Properties)...

> Named inputs are added to their owner form instance as properties, and can overwrite native properties if they share the same name (eg a form with an input named `action` will have its `action` property return that input instead of the form's `action` HTML attribute).

jQuery attempts to execute that function when programmaticaly submitting the form with something like

```js
if (typeof element.submit === 'function') {
  element.submit()
}
```

But in your case, `element.submit` is an `HTMLInputElement`.

Quick and easy solution, rename your *submit* element, or as is more commonly seen with single-button forms, just remove the `name` attribute.

---

If you **must** keep the submit button named *"submit"*, this seems to work

```js
function submitForm(form) {
  // note, "form" is already a jQuery object
  console.log(form.attr("method"));

  HTMLFormElement.prototype.submit.call(form[0])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove name = submit in your input will resolve problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/64kl2l3wvk. I think because form.submit function is replaced by the the input with name = submit.